# Bluetooth serial readings on 0.96'' Adafruit OLED

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano, adafruit, display, hc-05

I am trying to display the readings of LDR connected to slave arduino through serial monitor of master arduino paired with bluetooth. I got the readings and it is working fine.

But when I connected OLED to the master arduino so that the LDR readings can be displayed on OLED as well as serial monitor, it is not displaying as expected.

So for simplicity I tried sending the word "hello" from slave to master. The code for slave is :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX

void setup() {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);  // this pin will pull the HC-05 pin 34 (key pin) HIGH to switch module to AT mode
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  BTSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  BTSerial.println("hello");
  Serial.println("hello");
  delay(1000);

}
```

Then I tried displaying the same only on serial monitor of master. The code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX
char state ;

void setup() {
 pinMode(9, OUTPUT);  // this pin will pull the HC-05 pin 34 (key pin) HIGH to switch module to AT mode
 digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
 BTSerial.begin(9600);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() {
 if (BTSerial.available()) {
   state = BTSerial.read();
   Serial.write(state);
 }
}
```

It is showing valid readings in serial monitor with hello being printed after every one second

```
<Arduino is ready>
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

But when I modified the code so that I can get the readings on OLED as well as serial monitor;

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
char sensor;
void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);// initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C (for the 128x32)(initializing the display)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BTSerial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);  // this pin will pull the HC-05 pin 34 (key pin) HIGH to switch module to AT mode
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
}

void displayreading()
{
   if (BTSerial.available()) //checks for incoming data
    {

      sensor = BTSerial.read();//reads data from bluetooth serial
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(30,0); 
      display.setTextSize(1);
      display.print("LDR Reading:");
      display.setCursor(30,10); 
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.print(sensor); 
      Serial.write(sensor); 
    }
}

void loop()
{
    displayreading();
    display.display();
}
```

The OLED is showing one letter at a time clearing the screen after every letter rapidly (since I did not add delay which will add up to the problem of data lag). Like :
h , (clear screen)
e (clear screen)
l (clear screen)
l (clear screen)
0 (clear screen)

The serial monitor is showing the readings as:

```
<Arduino is ready>
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

But the word hello is printed letter after letter and not in a whole like in the previous master code.There is one second gap after every printing of "hello".

Can somebody please help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `BTSerial.read()` reads a single byte.

Comment: and serial write seems working ok, because there you don't move cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of BTSerial.read(); there should be

```
String content = "";
char character;

while(BTSerial.available()) {
     character = BTSerial.read();
     content.concat(character);
 }
```

and then you send content to lcd by putting

```
display.write(content);
```